Возможно ли совместить update абстрактного класса с наследником?
У меня есть несколько классов врагов, которые наследуются от абстрактного класса. Мне нужно в Update у каждого класса писать _currentFramesInvulnerability -= Time.deltaTime;. Возможно ли указать это в абстрактном классе, если в наследуемых классах врагов в update есть еще другие строки кода? Сначала я подумал про override, но если я правильно понимаю, то тогда  эта строка не будет выполняться.

Делается просто: добавляется абстрактный метод, например AdditionalUpdateOp, который все наследники должны реализовать. А в методе Update абстрактного класса пишется:
_currentFramesInvulnerability -= Time.deltaTime;
AdditionalUpdateOp();

Собственно всё. В наследниках просто реализуется метод AdditionalUpdateOp никак не трогая никогда Update.

Так-то можно реализовать и с override, не добавляя лишних методов: protected override void Update() { base.Update(); AdditionalUpdateOp(); }

@Vladimir не понял.  Во-первых вы всё также приписали вызов AdditionalUpdateOp(), во-вторых - помнить, что надо вызвать Update у базового класса - труднее, нежели реализовать обязательно запрашиваемый метод. Контроля с таким подходом больше, т.к. разработчик не забудет что-то реализовать. Ну и если в каждом классе писать вызов метода предка, а потом человек передумает реализовывать, то потом придётся перелопачивать все классы, вместо того, чтобы поправить один конкретный

C AdditionalUpdateOp согласен, мой косяк, там должно было быть // код наследника. Что касается остального, то лучше описать разные подходы, чем предлагать только один конкретный.

@Vladimir тут каждый может оставить ответ. Я оставил тот, который считаю нужным. Вы - можете добавить тот, который вы считаете правильным

Я не считаю ваш ответ неправильным. Тем не менее, его можно было бы сделать лучше, дополнив. Поэтому я оставил комментарий. Тут каждый может оставить комментарий. Я оставил тот, который считаю нужным.

@Vladimir вы можете оставить ответ, который считаете нужным

Увы,не сработает, всё равно нужно будет вызывать base.Update() в переопределённом методе производного класса.

@Qwer вообще-то всё работает: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgRBfl

@Алексей Шиманский Ок, идею понял - мы вообще отказываемся от метода Update в производных классах и реализуем его логику исключительно в AdditionalUpdateOp. Но тогда нужно будет внимательно следить, чтобы погромист не написал в производном классе свой Update, т. к. именно он будет исполнятся Unity (будет захвачен через рефлексию). https://dotnetfiddle.net/wg26eg

@Qwer  в моём ответе чётко написано что нужно делать. И ни о каких Update в наследниках там речи не шло.... а вообще миллион разрозненных Update - это плохо.... самое оптимальное, как это у меня сделано в примере - все объекты складывать в некоторый список (назовём это пулом) и дальше в одном единственном Update вызывать у объектов пула Update. .... с разработчиками во всех командах и компаниях должны быть соглашения о ведении кода. Так называемый Code Convention, чтобы все писали в одном стиле и по одной конкретной договорённости, чтобы не было хаоса и внезапностей

@Qwer по поводу апдейтов:  https://unity.com/ru/blog/engine-platform/10000-update-calls   ...  https://www.mo4tech.com/unity-performance-optimization-scripts.html   ... где то было ещё написано про оптимизацию Call 10000 ... но это надо поискать внимательнее

public abstract class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float _currentFramesInvulnerability;

    protected virtual Update ()    
    {
        _currentFramesInvulnerability -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

public class Goblin : Enemy 
{
    protected override Update ()
    {
        base.Update(); // вызов метода Update класса, от которого наследуется текущий
        // Do some
    }
}

Но это плохая практика, если код virtual метода должен быть обязательно исполнен, необходимо следовать своему же контракту явным образом.
public abstract class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float _currentFramesInvulnerability;

    private Update ()
    {
        _currentFramesInvulnerability -= Time.deltaTime;
        OnFrameTick();
    }

    protected abstract OnFrameTick ();
}

public class Goblin : Enemy 
{
    protected override OnFrameTick ()
    {
        // Do some
    }
}

